# compare value in same table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create the Oracle function `MaximalDistance`
The function does not receives any values
The function return the maximal distance between all the items – a number
Two items distance is the squared difference between the production years
of the given items.
e.g:

```
(, ) = (PROD_YEAR _ − PROD_YEAR _ )^2 *( |TITLE_LENGTH_a- TITLE_LENGTH_b|)
```

Maximal distance is the maximal result of the distance calculation between
all the item pairs.
e.g. 
 `= max((, )|∀ ,  ∈ )`
I tried to add new column to table with total, but it's seem I can't add column in function

Comment: As I see it, you don't need to create any function. You just have to write a cartesian product of the items table with itself, do some arithmetic on your columns and apply MAX aggregate function on the expression

Comment: It would be great if you could explain it in terms of rows and columns and show in a tabular format with some sample rows and expected values from the function. Also, show us your code if  there are any.